# Proof that Euclidean and Uniform norm generate the same topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I'm teaching myself topology using a book I found. One of the exercises are to prove the following:

> Define a metric $d'$ on $ \mathbb{R}^n $ ny $d'(x,y) =max${$|x_1-y_1|,...,|x_n-y_n|$}. Show that the Euclidean metric and $d'$ generate the same topology on $ \mathbb{R}^n $.

I just want to know if my proof is valid or not.

To prove this I will use the following theorem:

> $d$ and $d'$ generate the same topology on $M$ if and only if for every $x \in M$ and every $r>0$, there exist positive numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $B_{r_1}^{(d')}(x) \subseteq B_{r}^{(d)}(x)$ and $B_{r_2}^{(d)}(x) \subseteq B_{r}^{(d')}(x)$.

With this theorem I just need to find $r_1$ and $r_2$. First, $r_1$ is the radius of a $d'$-ball in $d$-ball of radius $r$. My claim is the $r_1 = \frac{r}{\sqrt{n}}$.

 $d'$-balls would be squares (when n=2), cubes (when n=3), hyper-cubes (when n>3), but I'll just refer to it as a "square". The corner of a square is the point with the greatest Euclidean distance from the center. Lets consider a ball centered at the origin, one of the corners of a $d'$-ball of radius $r_1$, would be $(r_1,r_1)$, when $n=2$, $(r_1,r_1,r_1)$, when $n=3$, and so on. That corners Euclidean distance from the origin must be less than $r$. So we have

$\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n} r_1^2} < r$, squaring both sides will remove the radical

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} r_1^2 < r^2$, the left side is just adding the same thing $n$ times, so we then have
 
$n \cdot r_1^2 < r^2$, then divide both sides by n

$ r_1^2 <\frac{ r^2}{n}$, then take the principal root

$ r_1 <\sqrt{\frac{ r^2}{n}}$, and simplify

$r_1 = \frac{r}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Next, $r_2$ is the radius of a $d$-ball in $d'$-ball of radius $r$.  My claim is the $r_2 = r$.  The center of an edge of a square is the point with the least Euclidean distance from the center. Lets consider a $d'$-ball centered at the origin again, one of the edge centers would be $(r,0)$, when $n=2$, $(r,0,0)$, when $n=3$, and so on. No matter what $n$ is the Euclidean distance of the point from the center is always $r$. Thus, $r_2=r$.

QED

Comment: Yes, your proof looks correct!